# Windows phone app change color of pivot page items even odd

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have built Windows phone app now I  want to change pivot page items color on the base of even odd items.
How it is possible?  any solution will be appreciated.

Here is some code example:

```
<PivotItem
            x:Uid="PivotItem1"
            Margin="19,152,0,-29.5"
            Header="Inbox"
            CommonNavigationTransitionInfo.IsStaggerElement="True">
            <ListView x:Name="myInbox"
                IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick"
                ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True" FontSize="36" Margin="-18,-139,-0.167,55.333">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>

                    <DataTemplate>

                        <Grid >

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>

                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />

                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition MinHeight="30" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding Subject}" FontSize="22" Grid.Row="0"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Right" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding Date}" Grid.Row="0"></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>

            </ListView>
        </PivotItem>
```

I want to change color of item in code behind.

```
    public sealed partial class PivotPage : Page
    {

    void PageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (User.isLogedIn == false)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Login));
        }
        else
        {
            LoadInbox(myInbox);                
        }
    }

    public async void LoadInbox(ListView list)
    {

                list.ItemsSource = EmailManager.EmailInbox;
     }

    }
```

Email manager email inbox code

```
class EmailManager
{
    public static List<EmailMessage> EmailInbox;


 public EmailManager(){
   EmaiInbox.Add(new EmailMessage { Id = 1, Subject = "my email subject one with long long text header", Date = "12-Dec-2015 05:10", Contents = "Following the comments on the question, one possible answer would be to suscribe to the Loaded event of your page and call the Event method from there.", Sender = "abc@example.com" });
            EmaiInbox.Add(new EmailMessage { Id = 2, Subject = "my email subject 2", Date = "12-Dec-2015 07:25", Contents = "Following the comments on the question, one possible answer would be to suscribe to the Loaded event of your page and call the Event method from there.", Sender = "abc@example.com" });
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got solution, want to share.

if you want to change Foreground color of a list this simply use this:

`yourlist.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);`

in mine code:

```
else
    {
        LoadInbox(myInbox);                   
         /// myInbox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
          myInbox.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
          myOutbox.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
     }
```

Also you can change color of grid child item like this way:

```
public YourConstructor() // replace YourConstructor with your class name.
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
        this.navigationHelper.LoadState += this.NavigationHelper_LoadState;
        this.navigationHelper.SaveState += this.NavigationHelper_SaveState;


        foreach (var c in ContentRoot.Children)
        {
            if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBlock))
            {
                var c1 = c as TextBlock;
                c1.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);                  
            }

        }
    }
```

ContentRoot is grid of page.